# A extended euclid algorithm related problem

Tags: number-theory

A Linear Diophantine Equation is of the following form: 
Ax+By+C=0, where,gcd(A,B)=d and A=da,B=db.If (x1,y1) is a solution of the diophantine equation, every solution is of the form:
x=x1+bt,y=y1−at
∀t∈Z.
But how is it possible? Can anyone explain me it with better clarification?.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$ be two solutions of the equation.
We know $Ax_1+By_1+C=0=Ax_2+By_2+C\quad\Rightarrow\\
A(x_1-x_2)+B(y_1-y_2)=0\quad \Leftrightarrow\
da(x_1-x_2)+db(y_1-y_2)=0 \Rightarrow\\
a(x_1-x_2)+b(y_1-y_2)=0$

Since $GCD(a,b)=1$, we know that $b|(x_1-x_2) \Rightarrow (x_1-x_2)=tb$.

Similarly, we get $(y_1-y_2)=ra$ - note that, in order to solve the equation, we must have $r=-t$ (why?).

Hence we get $x_1=x_2+tb, y_1=y_2-ta$. Also note that, for every possible $t\in\mathbb{Z}$ this fulfills the equation, thus we are done.

**Edit:** Had a + instead of a minus before; sorry. The general idea remains unchanged